# BibLaTeX: Properly quoting titles containing quotes

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, csquotes

Please take a look at this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[shorthands=off,main=ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes} 

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{Asperger.1944,
  title = {Die „Autistischen Psychopathen“ im Kindesalter},
  author = {Asperger, Hans},
  date = {1944},
  journaltitle = {Archiv für Psychiatrie und Nervenekrankheiten},
  volume = {117},
  pages = {76--136},
  doi = {10.1007/BF01837709},
  langid = {german},
  number = {1}
}

@article{Brundson.2014,
  title = {Exploring the “fractionation” of autism at the cognitive level},
  author = {Brundson, Victoria and Happé, Francesca},
  date = {2014},
  journaltitle = {Autism},
  volume = {18},
  pages = {17--30},
  doi = {10.1177/1362361313499456},
  langid = {english},
  number = {1}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[language=auto,autolang=other,style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The nesting of the quotation marks is wrong. How can I have `csquotes`(I suppose?) change the original double marks in the titles to single ones? I'd rather not touch the original `.bib` file, but could replace the fancy quotation marks with straight ones (") if needed, or some similar simple changes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution™ here would be to use `\mkbibquote{...}` or `\enquote{...}` in the `.bib` file.

---

If this is out of the question, you can use a sourcemap to replace the quotation marks with `\enquote{...}`. The usual caveats applies: Regular expressions don't really do nesting very well, so this only works if you don't nest the quotation marks.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[shorthands=off,main=ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[language=auto,autolang=other,style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=title,
        match=\regexp{„(.*?)“},
        replace=\regexp{\\enquote\{$1\}}]
      \step[fieldsource=title,
        match=\regexp{“(.*?)”},
        replace=\regexp{\\enquote\{$1\}}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Asperger.1944,
  title        = {Die „Autistischen Psychopathen“ im Kindesalter},
  author       = {Asperger, Hans},
  date         = {1944},
  journaltitle = {Archiv für Psychiatrie und Nervenkrankheiten},
  volume       = {117},
  pages        = {76--136},
  doi          = {10.1007/BF01837709},
  langid       = {german},
  number       = {1}
}
@article{Brundson.2014,
  title        = {Exploring the “fractionation” of autism at the cognitive level},
  author       = {Brundson, Victoria and Happé, Francesca},
  date         = {2014},
  journaltitle = {Autism},
  volume       = {18},
  pages        = {17--30},
  doi          = {10.1177/1362361313499456},
  langid       = {english},
  number       = {1}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

It is also possible to use `csquotes`' *active quote* feature.

This feature comes in two flavours. With `\MakeOuterQuote` you only need one character, which serves as opening and closing mark at the same time. Obviously, this construction does not work for nested quotation marks, since

```
"Lorem "ipsum" dolor"
```

is ambiguous as to if we quote `Lorem`  and  `dolor` or if we have a nested quotation.
In particular such quotes cannot be nested inside an `\enquote`.

Hence, the simple `\MakeOuterQuote{"}` and `"` in the `.bib` file does not work.

Things do work, however, if we use separate opening and closing marks. The characters you can choose here should not have another meaning for TeX (so the obvious brackets and `<...>` are out). The following works

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[shorthands=off,main=ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[language=auto,autolang=other,style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}

\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Asperger.1944,
  title        = {Die «Autistischen Psychopathen» im Kindesalter},
  author       = {Asperger, Hans},
  date         = {1944},
  journaltitle = {Archiv für Psychiatrie und Nervenkrankheiten},
  volume       = {117},
  pages        = {76--136},
  doi          = {10.1007/BF01837709},
  langid       = {german},
  number       = {1}
}
@article{Brundson.2014,
  title        = {Exploring the «fractionation» of autism at the cognitive level},
  author       = {Brundson, Victoria and Happé, Francesca},
  date         = {2014},
  journaltitle = {Autism},
  volume       = {18},
  pages        = {17--30},
  doi          = {10.1177/1362361313499456},
  langid       = {english},
  number       = {1}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It’s not out of the question to modify the .bib file, but since it is constantly regenerated by external software, I much prefer your mapping solution. Luckily, quotes within quotes aren’t really a thing for book titles, so a regex is fine. Matter of fact, I have modified your approach to apply to all modes of fancy quoting (known to me, guillemets excluded), with a single regex: `match=\regexp{[„“](.*?)[“”]}`.